# Block overriding

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates

i have a footer block which look like that

```
<div class="art-Footer">
  <div class="art-Footer-background">        
  <div class="region region-copyright">
    <div id="block-menu-menu-footer-menu" class="block block-menu contextual-links-region">
      <div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
        <ul class="contextual-links">
          <li class="menu-list first"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-footer-menu/list&amp;destination=node">List links</a></li>
          <li class="menu-edit"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-footer-menu/edit&amp;destination=node">Edit menu</a></li>
          <li class="block-configure last"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/block/manage/menu/menu-footer-menu/configure&amp;destination=node">Configure block</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="first leaf"><a href="http://drupal.org" title="">About</a></li>
          <li class="leaf"><a href="/drupal7/" title="" class="active">Accessibility</a></li>
          <li class="leaf"><a href="/drupal7/" title="" class="active">Contact us</a></li>
          <li class="leaf"><a href="/drupal7/" title="" class="active">Feeds</a></li>
          <li class="leaf"><a href="/drupal7/" title="" class="active">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li class="last leaf"><a href="/drupal7/" title="" class="active">Terms of use</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /block -->
    <div id="block-block-2" class="block block-block contextual-links-region">
      <div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
        <ul class="contextual-links">
          <li class="block-configure first last"><a href="/drupal7/?q=admin/structure/block/manage/block/2/configure&amp;destination=node">Configure block</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make a special template file for it and called it block-menu-menu-footer-menu.tpl.php as I used to name the file in drupal 6 but it's not loading the file.
I tried everything, as they said in Drupal 7.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you clear theme registry cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tip on overriding block templates in Drupal](http://coldfrontlabs.ca/news/drupal-quick-tip-12-overriding-block-templates). It was written for Drupal 6 but there are general concepts that should still help you in 7 (like how to use [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)).

**Update:**
Here's the post when it was still working: 
http://web.archive.org/web/20110214075625/http://coldfrontlabs.ca/news/drupal-quick-tip-12-overriding-block-templates

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar template, and the filename I'm using is block--menu--menu-footer-menu.tpl.php
Just double checking, did you add the menu to the footer block in the admin controls (/admin/structure/block)?